# Python - formatting a file.write string with spaces

Tags: python

I have a program and reads from a .txt file that I have created using another python code. I'm having trouble finishing this one.

It needs to read the .txt and spit out the numbers in that file along with their sum. Here's what I've got so far:

```
 def main():
    total = 0
    myfile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
    for line in myfile:
        amount = float(line)
        total += amount
    print('End of file')
    print('Numbers in file add up to ', format(total, ',.1f'), end='')
    myfile.close()

main()
```

I get the error msg:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '11 13 11 7 7'
```

Comment: What's wrong? Your code is working so good.

Comment: Yes my codes work, but I can't get the random numbers to print out like 1 2 3 4 5  instead they print out 12345

Comment: try to use `print('Numbers in file add up to ', format(total, ',.1f'), end=' ')`? (see that space)

Comment: tried that.. it prints decimals then. I just need whole numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now, try this:

```
 def main():
    total = 0
    with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            for i in line.split():
                amount = float(i)
                total += amount
        print(line.strip(), 'End of file')
        print('Numbers in file add up to ', format(total, ',.1f'), end='')
        print()

main()
```

Because `line` is one line, and that is `'11 13 11 7 7'`.

So `float()` can't convert one string like that to float. And these codes use `split()` to split that string to a list like`['11', '13', '11', '7', '7']`. Then use `for` to  extract it.

And now, `float()` can convert `'11'`, `'13'`, etc. to float.

Comment: YAY!!! Is there a way to add a line that prints out the numbers that are in that .txt file?

Comment: what is the output looks like? an example?

Comment: oh sorry.. the output looks that I would like it to look like is:                      11 15 13 19 9 
End of file
Numbers in file add up to 67

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

def main():
    myfile = open('numbers.txt', 'w')
    total = 0
    for count in range(3,8):
        file_size = random.choice(range(5,19,2))
        myfile.write(format(str(file_size) + ' '))
        total += file_size
    myfile.write(format(total))
    myfile.close()
main()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by separate codes. I see your above comment about the numbers being printed next to each other without spaces in between, but my file output shows spaces in between the numbers when I use my code. Or do you mean something different, now?

Comment: sorry maybe I could have used different wording. So I have 2 codes that basically do your 1 code if you will. My first code creates the .txt doc with the number then my 2nd code reads from that .txt and spits out the numbers and their sum. Does that make sense?